# Angular Rails Not Resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

We currently have some hardcoded code:

```
ng-form class="form-horizontal" name="genderForm">
      <div data-fields="">
        <div class="form-field-gender control-group form-field" data-field="">
          <div class="controls" data-input="">
            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="appuser.traits[6]" ng-value= "[42198]" name="field-input-gender" id="field-input-gender-0" required>
              <i class="fa fa-male fa-fw"></i> {{genderQuestion.traits[0].value_text}}
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="field-input-gender" ng-model="appuser.traits[6]" id="field-input-gender-1" ng-value="[42199]" required>
              <i class="fa fa-female fa-fw"></i> {{genderQuestion.traits[1].value_text}}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="text-error" data-error="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ng-form>
```

Ideally it will be dynamic so it should be something like this:

```
ng-form class="form-horizontal" name="genderForm">
      <div data-fields="">
        <div class="form-field-gender control-group form-field" data-field="">
          <div class="controls" data-input="">
            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="appuser.traits[{{genderQuestion.id}}]" ng-value= "[{{genderQuestion.traits[0].id}}]" name="field-input-gender" id="field-input-gender-0" required>
              <i class="fa fa-male fa-fw"></i> {{genderQuestion.traits[0].value_text}}
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="field-input-gender" ng-model="appuser.traits[6]" id="field-input-gender-1" ng-value="[{{genderQuestion.traits[1].id}}]" required>
              <i class="fa fa-female fa-fw"></i> {{genderQuestion.traits[1].value_text}}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="text-error" data-error="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ng-form>
```

But something about going from `ng-model="appuser.traits[6]"` to `ng-model="appuser.traits[{{genderQuestion.id}}]"` and `ng-value="[42199]"` to `ng-value="[{{genderQuestion.traits[1].id}}]"` seems to make it spazz out and not resolve any of the `{{}}` fields.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Technically `genderQuestion.id` = `6` and `genderQuestion.traits[1].id` = `42199` but in this format it doesn't seem to like those.

Maybe I'm missing like a `toString` format or something?

Comment: You don't need `{{ }}` again to be evaluated `appuser.traits[genderQuestion.id]` should work.

Comment: That definitely did it. Want to add it as an answer and I'll accept? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 way data binding with the `ngModel` directive doesn't need `{{ }}` again. You can directly refer to the scope object with `genderQuestion.id` 
`appuser.traits[genderQuestion.id]`.

Ta